# How to optimize search query work fast?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, query-optimization

```
query = "SELECT" + " e.id AS _id," + " ke.id AS ke_id,"
            + " ke.fk as ke_fk," + " ke.value as ke_value,"
            + " re.id AS ke_id," + " re.fk as re_fk,"
            + " re.value as re_value," + " s.id AS  s_id,"
            + " s.fk as s_fk," + " g.id AS g_id," + " g.fk as g_fk,"
            + " g.lang," + " g.value as g_value" + " FROM entry e"
            + "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk"
            + "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk"
            + "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk"
            + "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk"
            + " WHERE re.value like '" + hiragana
            + "%' OR g.value like '" + lookingFor
            + "%' OR g.value like '%" + strSpace + lookingFor
            + "%' GROUP BY s.id LIMIT 5 ";
```

This query takes data from SQLite database and taken data is put into listview. It is working very slow even if I have put LIMIT 5. What should be done in order to make search work fast?

Comment: You might look into full-text searching. I believe Android builds support SQLite's FTS extensions. http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: So I cannot use it now? :(

Answer (score 1):

NOt a SQLLite expert but these are the types of things I would look at from experience with other databases. You may need to experiement though.

First check your indexing. Next do you really need to have a wildcard as the first character? That usuallly makes a query slow in most databases implementations becausue it won't allow you to use an index on that particular field. I also can point out that in many databases a UNION or UNION ALL query is much faster than using ORs in the WHERE clasue.

Comment: What is indexing? I heard about it. But I do not have understanding what is that. How can it help to make search faster?

Comment: You need to go read about indexing, you have no business ever using any database without a strong knowledge of what is a complex subject.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the number of joins and/or conditions of the where clause.  You could just bring all the data into memory and using java reduce the desired result set to what you want.

Comment: This is minimum number of joins which I could do."You could just bring all the data into memory". What does this mean?

Answer (score -2):

I think such as complicated processing have to bee done server side .

Comment: Complicated? Not hardly.

Comment: Server side? If it fasten this search, how to do it?